# Strange 301 redirect problem

Tags: apache, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect all URLs that start with "/?page=" to "/stuff/?page="

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?page=/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/stuff/$1
```

But it's not working.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^/stuff/?page=$ /?page=/
```

Remember, you're effectively turning the right (of the space) into the left.

Answer (score 0):

The directives of [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) (one of them is [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)) do only work on the [URI path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax) and not the query. If you want to inspect the query, use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=
RewriteRule ^$ /stuff/ [L,R=301]
```